Rust Debug Rc pointer not show
When print debug information, the Rc pinter not show. why is that?
    type OptNode = Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>;
    impl Solution {
        pub fn is_valid_bst(root: OptNode) -> bool {
            return Self::helper(&root, i64::MIN, i64::MAX);
        }

        pub fn helper(root: &OptNode, gt: i64, lt: i64) -> bool {
            println!("{:?}", root);
            match root.as_ref() {
                None => true,
                Some(n) => {
                    let b = n.borrow();
                    println!("{:?}", b);
                    // println!("{}", i32::MAX);
                    (b.val as i64) > gt && (b.val as i64) < lt 
                        && Self::helper(&b.left, gt, b.val as i64)
                        && Self::helper(&b.right, b.val as i64, lt)
                }
            }
        }
    }

Some(RefCell { value: TreeNode { val: 2, left: Some(RefCell { value: TreeNode { val: 1, left: None, right: None } }), right: Some(RefCell { value: TreeNode { val: 3, left: None, right: None } }) } })
TreeNode { val: 2, left: Some(RefCell { value: TreeNode { val: 1, left: None, right: None } }), right: Some(RefCell { value: TreeNode { val: 3, left: None, right: None } }) }

Some(RefCell { value: TreeNode { val: 1, left: None, right: None } })
TreeNode { val: 1, left: None, right: None }
Rust debug information explain

The implementation of Debug on Rc directly delegates to the Debug implementation of the contained value:
impl<T: ?Sized + fmt::Debug, A: Allocator> fmt::Debug for Rc<T, A> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Debug::fmt(&**self, f)
    }
}

So the answer to your question is that it doesn't because... it doesn't.
RefCell's implementation, on the other hand, uses debug_struct to notate that the value is a RefCell.  Presumably it does this because it has to borrow the inner value to display it, which can fail if the value is already borrowed mutably, so the fact that the value is wrapped in a RefCell can be important to understand the output, while it's not important for Rc.
impl<T: ?Sized + Debug> Debug for RefCell<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result {
        let mut d = f.debug_struct("RefCell");
        match self.try_borrow() {
            Ok(borrow) => d.field("value", &borrow),
            Err(_) => d.field("value", &format_args!("<borrowed>")),
        };
        d.finish()
    }
}

Note that Rc is not alone in this behavior of omitting itself from the debug output; Box and Arc (and probably a few other wrappers / smart pointers) do the same thing.
